# How to iterate over a Queue I implemented myself?

Tags: java

I'm trying to debug a part of a program that peeks at a queue object from a queue class I implemented myself, so I'm trying to iterate over it and print out all the elements to see what's wrong without altering the queue. How can I do this?

My Queue class (QueueLinkedList is the name):

```
public class QueueLinkedList<Customer> implements Queue<Customer> {

    Node first, last;

    public class Node {
        Customer ele;
        Node next;
    }

    public QueueLinkedList() {}

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return first == null;
    }

    public QueueLinkedList<Customer> enqueue(Customer ele) {
        Node current = last;
        last = new Node();
        last.ele = ele;
        last.next = null;

        if (current == null) 
            first = last;
        else 
            current.next = last;

        return this;
    }

    public Customer dequeue() {
        if (isEmpty()) 
            throw new java.util.NoSuchElementException();

        Customer ele = first.ele;
        first = first.next;     
        return ele;
    }

    public Customer peek() {
        Customer ele = first.ele;
        return ele;
    }
```

Comment: It misses some code. `QueueLinkedList()` constructor should be in a `QueueLinkedList` class. There, it cannot compile fine.

Comment: This is the QueueLinkedList class

Comment: You'll have to implement the `Iterable` interface and create an `Iterator` for it.

Comment: To maximize your compatibility with the Java language and libraries, have your class implement `java.lang.Iterable<Customer>`, and define a `java.lang.Iterator<Customer>` class.

Answer (score 2):

You're using a linked-list to implement your queue. You can iterate over it just like you would iterate over any linked-list.

```
public void iterate() {
    Node iterator = first;
    while(iterator != null) {
        Customer customer = iterator.ele;
        // do something with the customer
        iterator = iterator.next;
    }
}
```

Edit: If your use case needs returning the iterator then ideally you should implement the Iterable interface. That solution is already mentioned in one other answer. For the sake of extending this answer to your use case I'm providing the below code. It would work, but its NOT an "Object-Oriented" way of doing it.

```
public class QueueLinkedList<Customer> implements Queue<Customer> {

    private Node iterator;

    // ...

    public QueueLinkedList() {
        iterator = null;
        // ...
    }

    public Node iterator() {
        iterator = first;
        return iterator;
    }

    public boolean hasNext() {
        return iterator != null;
    }

    public Node next() {
        if(!hasNext()) {
            throw new NoSuchElementException();
        }
        Node next = iterator;
        iterator = iterator.next();
        return next;
    }

}
```

Usage:

```
QueueLinkedList queue = new QueueLinkedList();
// ...
Node iterator = queue.iterator();
while(queue.hasNext()) {
    Node next = queue.next();
    Customer customer = next.ele;
    // do something with the customer
}
```

Comment: Thank you. But now it says I need to use a method that returns an Iterator, so something like public Iterator iterate(). What should I add as a return statement? Do I return (Iterator) iterator? Or do I return null or what?

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement `Iterable<Customer>` in your queue, as shown below, so that your queue can be iterated the same as arrays and other Java collections.

```
import java.util.*;

public class QueueLinkedList<Customer>
    implements Queue<Customer>, Iterable<Customer>
{

    Node first, last;

    public class Node {
        Customer ele;
        Node next;
    }

    class Iter implements Iterator<Customer> {
        Node current = first;

        public boolean hasNext() {
            return current != null;
        }

        public Customer next() {
            if (!hasNext())
                throw new NoSuchElementException();
            Customer next = current.ele;
            current = current.next;
            return next;
        }

        public void remove() {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
        }
    }

    public QueueLinkedList() {}

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return first == null;
    }

    public QueueLinkedList<Customer> enqueue(Customer ele) {
        Node current = last;
        last = new Node();
        last.ele = ele;
        last.next = null;

        if (current == null) 
            first = last;
        else 
            current.next = last;

        return this;
    }

    public Customer dequeue() {
        if (isEmpty()) 
            throw new java.util.NoSuchElementException();

        Customer ele = first.ele;
        first = first.next;     
        return ele;
    }

    public Iterator<Customer> iterator {
        return new Iter();
    }
}
```

Note that the way you have declared your class, `Customer` is a generic *type parameter*, not the class `Customer`.  This is actually a good thing as it means you can use your `QueueLinkedList` class with any data type.  To make it clear that `Customer` is a type parameter, you should replace every occurrence of `Customer` with a class variable name comprised of a single uppercase letter such as `E`.

Alternatively, if you want `QueueLinkedList` to always be a queue of `Customer` objects, you should change the class declaration to:

```
public class QueueLinkedList
    implements Queue<Customer>, Iterable<Customer>
```